# z-index not working properly with nth-child

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have three sortable lists here, but i don't want their property to change when their position is changed.For example i can prevent their color from changing but can't do the same thing with `z-index` i am using `nth-child` to do this here is my code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvEdMw

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>aaa</li>
<li>aaaasdsd</li>
<li>fgf</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li{
position:relative;
background-color:orange;
}

li:nth-child(1){
box-shadow:2px 2px 2px black;
z-index:3;
color:red;
}

li:nth-child(2){
box-shadow:2px 2px 2px black;
z-index:2;
color:blue;
} 

li:nth-child(3){
box-shadow:2px 2px 2px black;
z-index:1;
color:green;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('ul').sortable();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sortable` function of *jquery-ui* also makes use of `z-index`. It directly modifies the `style` of the element and is setting the `z-index` which overwrites your style.

One way how you can *fix*  that problem is by using `!important`  on the `z-index`.

```
li:nth-child(1){
  box-shadow:2px 2px 2px black;
  z-index:3 !important;
  color:red;
}
```

But I really don't like the usage of `!important`, as it might break other rules you have and will make your css code harder to maintain.

The other way would be to hook into the `stop` callback and cleanup the `z-index` set by the `sortable` plugin.

```
$('ul').sortable({
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).find('li').css('z-index','');
  }
});
```

Comment: @Akshay added the `stop` callback solution, as I think this might be the better way to solve it.